# mv file . deleted my file?

Tags: mv

I tried moving a file to my local directory with a very simple

```
mv /path/to/my/file .
```

... and now the file is just... gone? Not in the old directory, not in my current directory, simply not there. What could have happened

Comment: My bet would be that the working directory at the time you ran that command was not the one you thought it was, so the file is still somewhere. Try something like `find / -name file -ctime -1` to locate it.

Comment: Another (unlikely) possibility is that you renamed `file` to `.` followed by some invisible character. Run `ls -lartc | sed -n l` at the end of which you'll see the files with the most recent change time. The ctime of `.` itself will help determine if an entry was added (or modified) in the current working directory.